# Display Year and Month from custom field + Age Calculator

Tags: php, datetime, datetime-format

I have a custom field name "date_of_birth" on my custom post type which is in [Ymd] format on my database. Now, I want to compare that date of birth to current time and want to display "You are # years # months."

I am able to calculate Years only but it is not accurate. Help me.

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried so far

Answer (score 1):

You can use `date_diff()` function:

```
<?php

$diff = date_diff(date_create(), date_create('19951125'));
echo $diff->format("You are %Y Years and %M Months.");
```

Comment: Thank you Sky. It worked perfectly.
<?php

$diff = date_diff(date_create(), date_create(get_field('date_of_birth')));
echo $diff->format("You are %Y Years and %M Months."); ?>

Comment: @Sky - What if we need You are %Y Years and number of days instead of month ?